# Citation in bibliography when having multiple authors

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm using bibtex for writing references with natbib package. I'd like to ask how to cite more authors. If I use `\citet` command I get something like Green et al. Is it possible to use some modification for obtaining the same in my langauge? More precisely, I would need to get instead of "Green et al."  "Green a spol.", that is all.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example file, and a more complete description of your requirements.  Are you using `natbib`?  Do you want more authors named before the 'et al.' shows up? (If so, how many?)  What is your language in this case, and do you want your language's equivalent of 'et al.' (= et alii = and others)?

Comment: In order to automatically generate "a spol." instead of "et al.", it will be necessary to edit the bibliography style file you use. Which bibliography style -- that's the argument of the command `\bibliographystyle` -- do you use? Without this information, I'm afraid it's not going to be possible to give more-specific advice.

Comment: I'm using bibliography style jtbnew. However, I need to change this "a spol." instead of "et al." only in one record, not in all bibliography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that no matter what language you are writing in, *et al.* is a generally recognized form of citing multiple authors. Despite that, if you would really like to change it to something else, the easiest way would be using a custom `.bst` file based on the current style, where you would simply replace the occurrences with your custom string.

I quickly looked into the `abbrv.nat` style file for `natbib` and `et~al.` is hardcoded there with 4 occurrences.

Comment: I would need to get instead of "Green et al." "Green a spol." Is it possible to rename it?

Comment: Yeah, that should be possible without problems by simple changing the "et al." in the style file to `a spol.` (or better `a~spol.` to avoid a break)