# how to use citation in references

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Citation in bibliography when having multiple authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64704/citation-in-bibliography-when-having-multiple-authors)

I'm using bibtex for writing references with natbib package. If I use `\citet` command I get something like Green et al. Is it possible to use some modification for obtaining the same in other langauge? More precisely, I would need to get instead of "Green et al." "Green a spol."